# Make Django URLs work with or without /

Tags: python, django

I have a django app that has / at the end of every URL conf. Example:

```
# user home page
(r'^home/$', 'user_home_page'),
```

However, I'm noticing this is causing a ton of redirects on my server, because when people dont add the /, it redirects them. Is there any way to have it accept both without a redirect except doing:

```
# user home page
(r'^home$', 'user_home_page'),
(r'^home/$', 'user_home_page'),
```

or should I avoid URL confs like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While you can accept both without doing a redirect by using:

```
(r'^home/?$', 'user_home_page'),
```

It is not best SEO practice because it will look like you have duplicate content and your hits will be split between the two pages.

Answer (score 6):

You could modify your APPEND_SLASH Django setting, I haven't used it before.

> You may be wondering what happens if someone requests the URL /hello
>   (that is, without a trailing slash). Because our URLpattern requires a
>   trailing slash, that URL would not match. However, by default, any
>   request to a URL that doesn’t match a URLpattern and doesn’t end with
>   a slash will be redirected to the same URL with a trailing slash.
>   (This is regulated by the APPEND_SLASH Django setting, which is
>   covered in Appendix D.)

This was taken from http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03/

Answer (score 2):

The patterns are [Python regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).  How about:

```
(r'^home(/?)$', 'user_home_page'),
```

Answer (score 2):

> should I avoid URL confs like that?

Yes.  Django already handles this for you.

See this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.common

> If `APPEND_SLASH` is True and the initial URL doesn’t end with a slash,
>   and it is not found in the URLconf, then a new URL is formed by
>   appending a slash at the end. If this new URL is found in the URLconf,
>   then Django redirects the request to this new URL. Otherwise, the
>   initial URL is processed as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Use Django REMOVE_SLASH middleware instead.

https://gist.github.com/2204099

https://gist.github.com/gists/2204099/download

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure your application uses / consistently, make a choice which to use, and 301 redirect the rogue variation to the correct canonical one.

There should only be one version of a page, and the correct solution is in most cases to 301 redirect to the canonical version.

In some situations with additional paramenters for tracking you should also define a canonical in the head.

By using consistent URLs within your APP and out on the web in links pointing back to your app, you then won't have lots of redirects.